# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Logo

Tags: 16.04, files, lts, png, logo

Simple question - can someone running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS send me the file at `/usr/share/unity-greeter/logo.png`?

I've tried to find it online with no success

Comment: Just reinstall the package and you'll get your file back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [a link to that image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFPKb.png). Note that, though it may appear to be blank, it's actually white text with a transparent background.

Note that `apt-file search /usr/share/unity-greeter/logo.png` shows it's in the `unity-greeter` package, so you can also reinstall the image with the following command:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall unity-greeter
```

Comment: Thanks for the in-detail answer, however I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS but want the logo from the 16.04 LTS release, so reinstalling unity-greeter won't help.  The link worked though so thank you :)